# Половина каналов переведутся... Или переведётся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Вот предложение:
*...ещё мне не сказали, что спустя два месяца у меня **половина каналов переведутся** в демо режим.*

А вот вопрос: перевед**у**тся или перевед**ё**тся?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае возможны оба варианта согласования. — в ед. и мн. числе (по форме и по смыслу), но здесь следует применить следующее **правило Розенталя:**

При наличии в составе подлежащего **имени существительного** со значением определенного количества (тройка, сотня, пара и т.п.) сказуемое ставится в форме **единственного числа,** например: *Семерка велосипедистов устремилась вперед. Сотня ребят разбежалась во все стороны.*

Соответственно, выбирается согласование по форме (половина переведется): *...ещё мне не сказали, что спустя два месяца у меня **половина** каналов **переведется** в демо режим.*

Теорию можно посмотреть у Розенталя: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)